# SQL Server Primary Key for a range lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a static dataset that correlates a range of numbers to some metadata, e.g.

```
+--------+--------+-------+--------+----------------+
|  Min   |  Max   |Country|CardType|  Issuing Bank  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+----------------+
| 400011 | 400051 | USA   |VISA    | Bank of America|
+--------+--------+-------+--------+----------------+
| 400052 | 400062 | UK    |MAESTRO | HSBC           |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+----------------+
```

I wish to lookup a the data for some arbitrary single value

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE Min <= 400030 
  AND Max >= 400030
```

I have about 200k of these range mappings, and am wondering the best table structure for SQL Server?

A composite key doesn't seem correct due to the fact that most of the time, the value being looked up will be in between the two range values stored on disk.  Similarly, only indexing the first column doesn't seem to be selective enough.

I know that 200k rows is fairly insignificant, and I can get by with doing not much, but lets assume that the numbers of rows could be orders of magnitude greater.

Comment: why not create one aditional field `country_id` ? Would be much more faster than search between ranges and space cost is minimal.

Comment: All I have is the number.  It happens to be the first 6 digits of a credit card, which we need metadata for.  In practice, there are lots of columns of metadata, e.g. issuing bank,  card-number length etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *usually* search on both `min` and `max` then a compound key on `(min,max)` is appropriate.  The engine will find all rows where `min` is less than X, then search within those result to find the rows where `max` is greater then `Y`.

The index would also be useful if you do searches on `min` only, but would not be applicable if you do searches only on `max`.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the first number and then do the lookup like this:

```
select t.*,
       (select top 1 s.country
        from static s
        where t.num >= s.firstnum 
        order by s.firstnum
       ) country
from sometable t;
```

Or use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, s.country
from sometable t outer apply
     (select top 1 s.country
      from static s
      where t.num >= s.firstnum 
      order by s.firstnum
     ) s
```

This should take advantage of an index on `static(firstnum)` or `static(firstnum, country)`.  This does not check against the second number.  If that is important, use `outer apply` and do the check outside the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I belive is easy/faster if you create a trigger for `INSERT` and then fill the related calculated columns  `country, issuing bank, card-number length`

At the end you do the calculation only once, instead 200k every time you will do a query. Of course is there a space cost. But query will be much easier to mantain.

I remember once I have to calculate some `sin` and `cos` to calculate distance so I just create the calculated columns once.

### After your update I think is even easier

```
+--------+--------+-------+--------+----------------+----------+
|  Min   |  Max   |Country|CardType|  Issuing Bank  | TypeID   |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+----------------+----------+
| 400011 | 400051 | USA   |VISA    | Bank of America|    1     |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+----------------+----------+
| 400052 | 400062 | UK    |MAESTRO | HSBC           |    2     |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+----------------+----------+
```

Then you Card will also create a column `TypeID`

Answer (score 0):

I would specify the primary key on `(Min,Max)`.  Queries are as simple as:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE @Value BETWEEN Min AND Max
```

I'd also define a constraint to enforce that `Min <= Max`.  Then I would [create a trigger](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLPreventRangeOverlap.aspx) to enforce uniqueness in ranges and prevent the database from storing an overlapping range.